# Configure Tomcat 8 with Angular

Tags: angular, apache, tomcat

i'm trying to deploy my angular app on my local apache tomcat 8 server.

I used ng build --prod and copy paste the result of dist here.

[Location of my app on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoSNm.png)

I put `<base href="/caquiweb/">` to my index.html.

So, I can reach my application, and routing works, but 404 when manually changing URL in browser to defined router route.

[Working url by using routerLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/me3Hh.png)

[404 manually changing from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6P1S.png)

I think that i have to configure my server but i don't really know what to do.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution from my perspective:

- Add a `WEB-INF/web.xml` in `tomcat/webapps/caquiweb`, which has the following contents:

```html
<web-app>
    <error-page>
         <error-code>404</error-code>
         <location>/index.html</location>
     </error-page>
</web-app>
```

That way Tomcat redirects to `index.html` every time a URL is not found, which then leads Angular to handle it with the component router.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't look legit. What if you get a *real* 404? Furthermore I believe that the Tomcat would send the index.html, but still with status code 404, which is not correct (must be 200 for OK responses)

Comment: An actual 404 would be handled by the Angular router, where you would redirect to an error component. I've used that solution with success for a client of mine. I would not post something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of the PathLocationStrategy routing in angular application.

The context path of your application is `/caquiweb/`.

You setting in index.html should be - `<base href="/">`

You have to build the application using - `ng build --base-href /caquiweb/`

You have to configure the rerouting of deep links to the application root index.html as below -

1. Configure the RewriteValve in server.xml
2. Write the rewrite rule in rewrite.config

server.xml -

```
...
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

...
      </Host>
...
```

rewrite.config - (location - {tomcatHome}/conf/Catalina/localhost)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/caquiweb/(.*) /caquiweb/index.html
```

For detailed instruction you can refer the article - [Fixing deep linking issue – Deploying angular application on Tomcat server](http://codedumpster.nithinbiliya.com/deep-linking-issue-angular-application-tomcat-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the rewrite in a programmatic way as described in this great post: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/packaging-your-spring-boot-and-angular-2-projects-together-a13a9c5efdb7.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't need to change anything on the server. The unique file you need to change is your deployment descriptor file, in this case your web.xml file, to register you filter. Another advantage is that you could give angular the ability do handling just its routes. So if you try to access a resource, like a file or a endpoint in the server, and this resource doesn't exist, you will get a true 404.